# Select Handsontable header cells

Tags: jquery, handsontable

Using Handsontable it is easy to select all of the cells you want with the built in click and drag functionality. Unfortunately this behavior doesn't extend to the column or row headers which are unselectable. If i want to be able to copy/ paste all the info from my table including the headers is there any way to achieve this while still preserving the header appearance?

I have been able to achieve this functionality by changing the headers to just be another row or column however for styling reasons this is undesirable. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a feature request. The handsontable team is very active on their github repo. Just link your question there https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues
Maybe try to add a basic fiddle to get started too. Normally you get a response in 1 day.

Comment: Did you found an answer on their github page?